# Can I redistribute dao360.dll and acedao.dll?

Tags: ms-access, dll, dao, redistributable

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/cc811599(v=office.12)) and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11245/How-to-use-DAO-in-Visual-C-without-MFC), I know one can use direct DAO to manage Access database. Therefore, I just wonder if it is possible to redistribute acedao.dll and dao360.dll mentioned in the first and second article?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Both dao360.dll and acedao.dll are included in the Microsoft Access Database Engine redistributable.

When writing this answer, the latest version is the 2016 version, downloadable [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920).

Comment: Thank you. Then need I distribute these two DLL files individually, or distribute the whole "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable". I see the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable" is rather huge(77MB for 32bit and 79 for 64bit.

Comment: @alancc Afaik you need the whole database engine, but I've never truly tested it. If size is a problem, you can try the 2010 redistributable, which is less than half the size of the 2016 redistributable and mainly lacks `BigInt` support, or the 2007 database engine which also lacks support for data macro's.